# Using Qt Database in Large Application

Tags: database, sqlite, qt

I have a question regarding using Databases in Qt.

In other languages I would do something like create a database in the main class and pass a pointer of this database to other classes to use.

I have been playing around in Qt and it seems that if I initialize a database in the main class then I can just write and execute a query in any other class and it will use this database and I am a bit confused because there seems to be no reference to a database.

Could someone explain this for me :)

Here is the Database class which is instanced in MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "database.h"

Database::Database()
{
    Connect();
}

void Database::Connect()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("mydatabase­.dat");

    if(db.open()){
        qDebug() << "Connected";
    }
    else
    {
         qDebug() << "Not Connected";
    }
}

bool Database::SetupTables()
{
    QSqlQuery qry;

    qry.exec("CREATE TABLE patients ( patient_id INT, firstname VARCHAR(100), lastname VARCHAR(100) );  ");

    return true;
}
```

Here is a Window (Widget) i created called PatientList

```
#include "patientlist.h"
#include "ui_patientlist.h"
#include "database.h"
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>

PatientList::PatientList(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PatientList)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSqlQuery qry;
    if(qry.exec("SELECT patient_id,firstname,lastname FROM patients")){
        qDebug() << "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error";
    }

}

PatientList::~PatientList()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

This all works fine but I just feel like im doing something wrong because I have not mentioned the database created in the MainWindow.cpp

Comment: Can you show us some example code? This is incredibly vague

Answer (score 2):

From Qt documentation on [QSqlDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#details):

> A connection is known by its own name, not by the name of the
>   database it connects to. You can have multiple connections to one
>   database. QSqlDatabase also supports the concept of a default
>   connection, which is the unnamed connection. To create the default
>   connection, don't pass the connection name argument when you call
>   addDatabase(). Subsequently, when you call any static member function
>   that takes the connection name argument, if you don't pass the
>   connection name argument, the default connection is assumed.

Well, I think this says it all. Note that QSqlDatabase cannot be directly instantiated. Direct creating instance of QSqlDatabase will only produce invalid connection. Apparently a QSqlDatabase are only links to actual connection objects (probably allocated statically). As many applications are likely to use only one database connection, one link is singled-out as default.

I am unsure if this is done on per-application or per-thread basis.

Answer (score 0):

Well not seeing your main makes it difficult but it looks like QSqlQuery is smart enough to pick up your "default" database. See here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2

So as long as you're seeing values in your db, I'd say it's just another example of Qt doing something not necessarily intuitive but ultimately very easy to use.